# i want to maintain the totalNumberOfRecords in this while each time i call this method

Tags: c#

i call this method frequently but when the searchcolumn is first it has to call totalNumberOfRecords methods next time when i call this method it should maintaintain tototalNumberOfRecords.

```
public static EGResponse<List<Assets>> GetPlantAttributes(string templateId, string searchColumn, string searchValue, string pageCount)
    {
        string query = string.Empty;
        //int totalNumberOfRecords = 0;
        List<Assets> summary = null;
        DateTime currentdate=DateTime.Now;
        EGResponse<List<Assets>> resp = new EGResponse<List<Assets>>(EGResult.Failure, null, EGDataLayer.CommonUtility.OPERATIONFAIL);
        int totalNumberOfRecords;

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchColumn) && searchColumn == "Empty")
        {
            totalNumberOfRecords = 0;
            pageCount = "0";
        }
        else
        {
            ////if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchValue) && searchValue == "Empty" && totalNumberOfRecords<0)
            //{
            //    totalNumberOfRecords = GetCountOfPlantAttributes(searchColumn, searchValue);
            //}

            //totalNumberOfRecords = GetCountOfPlantAttributes(searchColumn, searchValue);
            if (pageCount.ToLower() == "first" && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchValue) )
            {
                pageCount = "0";
                totalNumberOfRecords = GetCountOfPlantAttributes(searchColumn, searchValue);
            }

            if (pageCount.ToLower() == "last")
            {
                //totalNumberOfRecords = GetCountOfPlantAttributes(searchColumn, searchValue);
                pageCount = (totalNumberOfRecords / 20).ToString();
            }
        }
```

The method for GetCountOfPlantAttributes will return the totalNumberOfRecords  in the datatable.

Comment: Okay so what's the issue?

Answer (score 0):

> next time when i call this method it should maintaintain
>   tototalNumberOfRecords.

No, that's not possible since it's a local variable (local to the method) as seen in below code and thus will be out of scope once method execution is over. If you want to retain it then  use some kind of storing mechanism .. either in flat-file or DB or Cache etc... again if it's any web application then you can use `session` but not sure about that from your post

```
public static EGResponse<List<Assets>> GetPlantAttributes(string templateId, string searchColumn, string searchValue, string pageCount)
    {
        string query = string.Empty;
        .....
        int totalNumberOfRecords;
```

Comment: from the ajax post the service this method

Comment: @suganya, then as stated in answer you can either use `Session` or `Cache`. see MSDN for more information

Answer (score 0):

If you are completely sure you that your method will not be called from multiple threads at the same time you could move totalNumberOfRecords outside your method as a static field.

Comment: really? OP says it's a web application. Now what you suggest?

Comment: How about: `int totalNumberOfRecords = HttpContext.Current.Session["totalNumberOfRecords"]
                ? (int) HttpContext.Current.Session["totalNumberOfRecords"]
                : 0;` and save totalNumberOfRecords when it's counted. `totalNumberOfRecords = HttpContext.Current.Session["totalNumberOfRecords"] = GetCountOfPlantAttributes(searchColumn, searchValue);`